# clock_nanosleep() does not return immediately (when it should) [WSL 2]

Tags: linux, posix, windows-subsystem-for-linux, scheduling, glibc

I am using clock_nanosleep() with the TIMER_ABSTIME flag to maintain loop timing. This is being run in WSL2. The clock_nanosleep() man page states:

> If flags is TIMER_ABSTIME, then request is interpreted as an absolute time as measured by the clock, clockid.  If request is less than or equal to the current value of the clock, then clock_nanosleep() returns immediately without suspending the calling thread.

In my case, the requested time is indeed <= current time and yet clock_nanosleep() does not return right away. It seems that the thread goes to sleep, and a context switch occurs.

Below is a reproducible example, and the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

#define timespeccmp(tvp, uvp, cmp)                  \
    (((tvp)->tv_sec == (uvp)->tv_sec) ?             \
        ((tvp)->tv_nsec cmp (uvp)->tv_nsec) :           \
        ((tvp)->tv_sec cmp (uvp)->tv_sec))
#define timespecadd(tvp, uvp, vvp)                      \
    do {                                \
        (vvp)->tv_sec = (tvp)->tv_sec + (uvp)->tv_sec;      \
        (vvp)->tv_nsec = (tvp)->tv_nsec + (uvp)->tv_nsec;   \
        if ((vvp)->tv_nsec >= 1000000000) {         \
            (vvp)->tv_sec++;                \
            (vvp)->tv_nsec -= 1000000000;           \
        }                           \
    } while (0)

static struct timespec nextcnt_spec;
static struct timespec tick_spec = {0UL, 1000000000UL / 250};
struct timespec nothing = {.tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = 0};
struct timespec now_spec;

int main(int argc, int *argv[])
{
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &nextcnt_spec);
  timespecadd(&nextcnt_spec, &tick_spec, &nextcnt_spec);

  while (1)
  {
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now_spec);
      if (timespeccmp(&now_spec, &nextcnt_spec, >=))
      {
          timespecadd(&nextcnt_spec, &tick_spec, &nextcnt_spec);
      }

      printf("now: %d.%d\n", now_spec.tv_sec, now_spec.tv_nsec);
      clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &nextcnt_spec, NULL);
  }
}
```

```
now: 82942.980959346
now: 82942.997138210
now: 82943.13317148
now: 82943.29403662
now: 82943.45508177
now: 82943.61593249
now: 82943.77658352
now: 82943.93719126
now: 82943.109841360
now: 82943.125951165
```

If it's useful, below are the relevant parts of my kernel config:

```
#
# Timers subsystem
#
CONFIG_TICK_ONESHOT=y
CONFIG_NO_HZ_COMMON=y
# CONFIG_HZ_PERIODIC is not set
CONFIG_NO_HZ_IDLE=y
# CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL is not set
# CONFIG_NO_HZ is not set
CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
# end of Timers subsystem

CONFIG_HZ_1000=y
CONFIG_HZ=1000
```